# Flask template extending issue

Tags: python, templates, flask

Flask template extension doesn't work for some reason.

I've created a basic flask app with the following file structure:
[image]

`__init__.py` is empty

The code from `app.py` is:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    app.run()
```

The code from `index.html` is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>from index</h1>

  {% block ext %}
  {% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

The code from `ext.html` is:

```
{% extends "index.html" %}

{% block ext %}

  <h2>from ext</h2>

{% endblock %}
```

When I run in command line `python app.py` it gives no errors or warnings, logs are just

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Sep/2017 14:48:40] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

But in the browser, the only output I have is "from index". So Flask doesn't see template extension from ext.html, and I don't see "from ext" in the browser.  What's wrong here? Is there a typo somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're rendering the wrong thing. Inheritance goes from child to parent; if you want the child template to be used, then that's what you need to call.

```
def index():
    return render_template("ext.html")
```